# Redis: INCRBY a BigFloat Number

Tags: redis

I'm going to use redis's `INCRBYFLOAT` command to a key-value pair. However, I retrieved the value from a BigFloat type. I'm not sure if I can directly pass the BigFloat variable to that command. If not, how do I convert it to a normal float? I'm actually programming in Golang, so it's of type `*big.Float`. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to pass it? ;P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the client library you are using. Most seem to require strings or []byte to be passed as arguments. Check the docs for the library you are using. I would be doubtful any accept big.Float.

To convert to a string I'd probably go with standard Go string formatting via fmt.